# Unity + Gnome 3 broke on update -- NVidia card -- OpenGL working

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia, gnome

Think the title is fairly clear (system specs below)

I cannot get Unity (2d works) nor Gnome 3 to load properly since an update run last Friday

thus far I've tried

- installing propietary drivers manually download from web-site reboot to system recovery console and install

  - Latest Long Lived Branch version: 295.59
  - Latest Short Lived Branch version: 302.17
- installing nvidia-current

  - the ubuntu default version at 295.40
  - the x-swat version (currently running) at version 3.02.XX (forget extension -- currently unable to switch windows to check)

including variations of tinkering with xorg.conf and such

current logs don't show any errors (will paste in once I get on a system that can switch windows to copy and paste over network) checking
 - dmesg
 - kern.log
 - Xorg.0.log

glxgears shows running 75 FPS under gnome 3 in a window so the OpenGL parts seem to be working, and nvidia-settings shows everything working fine, but I get a dependency error when I try to run gnome directly (again I'll paste in reference)

Gnome 3 Error

```
$ gnome-shell
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: Error: Requiring GjsDBus, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'GjsDBus' (any version) not found
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '0'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"gjs_throw"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"("Requiring GjsDBus, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'GjsDBus' (any version) not found")@gjs_throw:0 @/usr/share/gjs-1.0/overrides/Gio.js:23"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Requiring GjsDBus, version none: Typelib file for namespace 'GjsDBus' (any version) not found"'
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '24'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js:24"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function"'
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '24'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js:24"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function"'
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '24'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js:24"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function"'
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '24'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js:24"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function"'
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '24'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js:24"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function"'
JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function
JS ERROR: !!!     lineNumber = '24'
JS ERROR: !!!     fileName = '"/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js"'
JS ERROR: !!!     stack = '"@/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/misc/gnomeSession.js:24"'
JS ERROR: !!!     message = '"Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a function"'
Window manager warning: Log level 32: Execution of main.js threw exception: TypeError: Gio.DBusProxy.makeProxyWrapper is not a fun
```

any ideas? I'm plum out of gas to keep tackling this and found myself considering migrating this workstation to Windows after 4+ years of freedom...

Video: Nvidia GT 520
CPU: AMD Phenom II (dual core) 3.2GHz
RAM: 12GB DDR3

additional note 2 monitors are working properly, and I can boot into Unity 2D

booting into Gnome 3 loads a desktop where hotkeys work and all startup programs load but no gnome-shell which errors out when trying to run via console

Unity simply loads to the desktop where it is then non-responsive for a couple minutes and times out back to lightdm

(more log pastes shortly)